# Powerapps - No data in second screen (iPhone)

Tags: ios, powerapps

I have created an app that obtains the data of the company's workers from a shareppoint list (I use a gallery).
When starting the app the data is displayed correctly but when selecting a worker and passing data to a second screen in Iphone IOS 14.6 it does not show the data.
In Android and from the PC everything works correctly.
I have passed the data through the NAVIGATE function and have tested with a variable.

Thanks

Comment: This is a very generic description, can you perhaps share some code you are running? It will be easier to give an advice.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using global variables  with "Set()"
What is the type of data?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried:
My code in the Gallery onselect is:

```
Set (selectWorker; ThisItem) ;;
Navigate (DetailScreen1; ScreenTransition.Fade)
```

My code in the text label is:

```
text = selectWorker.name
```

I have also tried from Safari and Chrome installed on Iphone and it does not work. All correct on Android and PC.

Comment: Ensure you have the `name` column present in the gallery. If its not displayed in the gallery, `selectworker` will not contain it.